# Tkinter==>Label/Msg aoresentam apenas 1 item da lista.Como resolver?

Tags: python, tkinter

Bom, o objetivo é fazer com que, no mesmo label ou msg, todos os itens da lista
apareçam. Não sou muito experiente no Tkinter, então não sei se há um limite quanto a isso. Segue parte do código a seguir.

```
prod=['Exemplo-10.00','Exemplo2-20.00','Exemplo3-30.00']
##
def create_window():
    top = tk.Toplevel()
    top.title('Tabela de Preços')
    h=Message(top, width=310 , text='' )
    h.place(x=50,y=50)
    h.config(font=('Courier', 20))
    h.pack()
    def listagem():
        for i in prod:
            yo=int(i.find('-'))
            h['text']=str(i[0:yo]+'.......'+str(i[yo:-1]))
    bto=Button(top, width=22 , height=2 ,text='Clique para mostrar a tabela', command=listagem)
    bto.place(x=0,y=5)
    bto.pack()
    top.geometry('400x600+300+60')
```

Comment: Não é mais facil usar o listview no seu caso?

Comment: Sim, não conhecia e fui pesquisar. Obrigado!